# How much gold do characters and monsters get through the level progression of 21-40?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-advancement, treasure, mythic-adventures

How much gold do characters and monsters get through the level progression of 21-40?

Comment: Doesn't *Pathfinder* stop at 20? Can you link to the *Pathfinder* epic rules?

Comment: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/running-a-mythic-game/

Comment: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/

Comment: @HeyICanChan it does not. Character classes are capped at 20.

Comment: Per the experience chart, yes it does stop at 20. There are *unofficial* Epic rules (and you can port 3.5 material, obviously) but no official way to surpass 20 class levels.

Comment: Just so you know, "playing at levels above 20" and the "mythic heroes" rules have **nothing to do with each other**. A mythic character has a mythic "tier" *and* a character level, which will still be in the 1-20 range. You don't add the two together.

Answer (score 6):

### Pathfinder doesn't include much detail for levels beyond 20

Pathfinder's rules don't cover [advancement beyond level 20](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/#Advancing_Beyond_20th_Level) in very much detail. You get guidance on what attack/save/spell progression for advancing classes should look like, but beyond that it leaves things very much up to you.

Mythic tiers, as linked in your comments, are a different system of progression which is separate from normal character level. A character with mythic tiers is treated as having a slightly higher level for the purpose of [calculating encounter difficulty](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/running-a-mythic-game/#Sidebar_Adjusting_CR_and_Level):

> To adjust a character’s level, add half his tier (minimum 1) to his total character level. So a 10th-level/5th-tier character is effectively a 12th-level character for challenge and reward purposes, and a 20th-level/10th-tier character is effectively a 25th-level character for those purposes.
>
> To adjust a foe’s CR, add half its tier or rank (minimum 1) to its CR. So a 2nd-rank minotaur is effectively a CR 6 monster, while a 6th-tier champion pit fiend would be CR 23. For mythic monsters, this calculation has already been made.

But in terms of their expected wealth, there is [no difference between a character with mythic tiers and one without](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/running-a-mythic-game/#Rewarding_Mythic_Characters):

> Note that mythic characters will face fewer encounters to reach their next character level, but their XP and treasure totals should still fall relatively close to those of a non-mythic character of the same level.

Pathfinder doesn't offer any rules or guidance on how much wealth a character above level 20 would be expected to have, though the [table of expected treasure rewards per encounter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/#Table-Treasure-Values-per-Encounter) does include entries for *encounters* up to CR30.

### You could refer to 3.5e's epic progression

If you really are taking characters beyond 20th level, there were more detailed rules for this back in 3.5e's epic progression rules as given in the Dungeon Master's Guide, including a table for wealth-by-level up to level 40 on page 209. For levels 1-20, Pathfinder's expected wealth by level is roughly congruent with 3.5e's expected wealth by level - it seems like adding ~10-15% to the 3.5e values gets you to the Pathfinder figures, so you could do the same with 3.5e's values for levels 21-40 to get approximately sane values for Pathfinder.